# Changing attributes in Zope templates

Tags: plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

I'm writing a template for an object that contains files. I'm following the [theme building blocks instructions](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/buildingblocks/skin/templates/referencemanual-all-pages).

```xml
<a tal:attributes="href item/id">foo</a>
```

That makes that the liks downloads the file, as this:

```xml
<a href="foo">foo</a>
```

But I want that link points to the view page of the file, showing its title, description and also, allowing to download it. So I want to get the next output:

```xml
<a href="foo/view">foo</a>
```

How can I generate that attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `string:` expression adding the `/view` part:

```xml
<a tal:attributes="href string:${item/id}/view">foo</a>
```

Note that you probably want to use the `.absolute_url()` (for objects) or the `.getURL()` (for catalog results) methods instead to generate full absolute URLs for your items:

```xml
<a tal:attributes="href string:${item/absolute_url}/view">foo</a>
```